Calculating the area enclosed by three graphs, but two out of them already enclose a different area.
I have three functions :
$$y = 2x^2 + 2x \tag{1}$$
$$y = -x - 1 \tag{2}$$
$$x = 0 \tag{3}$$
Exercise asks for the area enclosed by three of those functions.
It is clear that the area from $x = \frac{-1}{2}$ to $x = 0$ is included, but the problem is $y = 2x^2 + 2x$ and $y = -x - 1$ also encloses another region on their own from $x = -1$ to $x = \frac{-1}{2}$.
So does the total region of the three functions accounts for that separately enclosed region?
Here's the graph :
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fqqngyi1ur

Normally, it would not be counted as it isn't bounded by the other plot. Though I'd prefer to use inequalities instead to avoid confusion

Is that how the question was actually worded? In most cases, it is probably just asking for the region from $x = -0.5$ to $x=0$, but it may be asking you to sum this area with the other region you mentioned. By the way, $x = 0$ is not a function.

It is actually worded that way. That's why there's ambiguity in how we can calculate  the total area.

I have updated my answer to high-light which area was intended & why.

I used your DESMOS Output to make this Image :

I have shaded & marked 4 general regions.
In general , (1) is the area between 2 functions & the $X$ Axis.
It could be Positive (above the Axis) or negative (below the Axis) like in this Case.
Then (2) is the area between 2 functions , where we have to Identify "Exactly" 2 Points of Intersection.
When there are more than 2 Intersections , it will be ill-defined & we have to give additional Criterion.
Moving to (3) , it is the area between some $X$ Co-ordinate (here it is $x=0$ ) & nearest Point of Intersection , which we have to Identify.
When there are Intersections on both sides of that $x$ Co-ordinate , it will be ill-defined & we have to give additional Criterion.
Lastly , (4) is the area between 2 functions between 2 $x$ Co-ordinates.
There are certain complications when there are Intersections between these limits , which I will not get into at the moment.
Coming to OP Case , we should know what the Exact Wording was to know what was intended.
Assuming certain things , we can say that Area (3) was to be calculated.
ADDENDUM :
OP is wondering whether it is (3) or (3)+(2) or (3)+(2)+(1).
Well , it can not be (3)+(2) or (3)+(2)+(1) because :
(A) In general , there might be multiple Intersections when $x$ is negative , like with 2 functions involving $sin$ terms. We can not go indefinitely backwards looking for all Intersections to include in the area.
(B) At every Intersection , Area Polarity changes & accounting for that is not standard. Certain Situations require that we add up the magnitudes. Certain Situation require that we add & subtract accordingly.
(C) Such Complications are not handled in Intro-Level text-books , hence we are left with only (3) to Evaluate.

It is your (A) in the addendum that clicks for me. It all makes sense now.

I did think that your confusion might be resolved with that , @DivineOrca , which was why I deliberately added that Section later ! There are more complications which I have avoided at the moment.
